# ¿Cómo modificar periodo de PWM en Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

Tengo como objetivo, comunicar 2 placas de arduino nano de forma que yo ingrese un texto en el emisor y se envíe al receptor en forma de PWM.

Ya que las salidas del PWM de arduino son de 8 bits he decidido aprovechar el código ASCII de forma que cada porcentaje del ciclo de trabajo del PWM sea el valor decimal del caracter que quiero transmitir. De forma muy sencilla lo he planteado en este código:

```cpp
/*
    Comunicación entre Arduino por PWM

Código necesario para programar el pin de salida PWM de Arduino
para que envíe una señal equivalente a un mensaje de texto en ASCII.

Se acondiciona la señal 0-255 coincidente con la tabla ASCII, de forma 
que DC = 0% - 100% sea iguala 0-255 bits.

*/

String Texto;
void setup(){
}

void loop(){

for(int i = 0; i < Texto.length(); i++){       // Recorro el texto
    analogWrite(6,(int)Texto.charAt(i));       // Para cada char escribo en el pin 6 su valor en ASCII
    }
}
```

Mi problema, es que no se la manera de cambiar la frecuencia o el período de la señal para poder conectarlas al osciloscopio y ver que funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Dependiendo de la plataforma existe una manera u otra de cambiar la frecuencia del PWM. Por ejemplo, en los casos de los microcontroladores ATmega168 y ATmega328 [tienes que programar los temporizadores que generan la señal PWM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM). En un arduino nano tienes tres temporizadores disponibles. También puedes ver código de ejemplo aquí: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency/

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Siento no poder darte algo más concreto (como código). Aunque tengo un Arduino Nano (entre otros), siempre uso la frecuencia por defecto para controlar servos o variadores. Para el ESP32-CAM sí que tengo código funcional porque tengo que generar un PWM que va directo a los motores mediante un puente H, de mayor frecuencia para que los motores no hagan ruido molesto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es complicado cambiar el periodo de la señal PWM directamente, por lo que la solución más simple es usar una librería. Personalmente recomiendo [TimerOne](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne). Con esta librería puedes regular los pines 9 y 10.

Regulas la señal PWM usando el objeto predefinido `Timer1`.

Primero tienes que inicializar el periodo, expresado en microsegundos. Digamos que queremos un periodo de un segundo, entonces escribes.

```
Timer1.initialize(1000000);
```

Luego usas `Timer1.pwm(pin, duty)` para cambiar el *duty cycle*, donde

- `pin` es el número de pin (9 o 10).
- `duty` es un `long` calculado como `1023 * duty_cycle / 100`.

Para *apagar* la señal, usas `Timer1.disablePwm(pin)`.

Aqui hay un programa de prueba para hacer parpadear un LED en pin 9:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

// Periodo de la señal PWM en segundos
#define PERIODO 1
// Pin controlado por Timer1 (puede ser 9 ó 10)
#define PIN_LED 9

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN_LED, OUTPUT);

  Timer1.initialize(PERIODO * 1000000);
  
  int duty = 50; // 50% HIGH, 50% LOW
  Timer1.pwm(PIN_LED, 1023L * duty / 100L);
}


void loop() {
}
```

**Hay mejores alternativas**

Sin embargo, usar PWM como medio de comunicación es una idea horrible, pues significa que el receptor tendrá que muestrear la señal de entrada para determinar su frecuencia (duty cycle) y asi recuperar el caracter enviado.

La solución simple y lógica es usar I2C, que te permite enviar y recibir bytes sin mayor esfuerzo.

I2C está disponible en Arduino y cualquier otro MCU del mercado.

Answer (score -2):

El término PWM proviene del inglés Pulse Width Modulation que significa modulación por ancho de pulsos. Una señal PWM es una señal digital similar al tren de pulsos cuadrados.

La principal diferencia con el tren de pulsos es que en la señal PWM, es posible variar el tiempo que la señal se mantiene en estado alto, pero siempre manteniendo el periodo constante, tal y como se muestra en la imagen siguiente.

Las salidas PWM con Arduino son muy útiles, por ejemplo, si quieres controlar la velocidad de un motor eléctrico, controlar el brillo de un LED o controlar un servomotor con Arduino.

Las [señales PWM](https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/pwm-con-arduino-analogico/) con Arduino son muy fáciles de utilizar gracias a la función analogWrite(). En este tutorial aprenderás todo lo necesario para poder utilizar señales PWM con [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/).

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta de como variar la frecuencia. Tampoco proporciona información útil o novedosa.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!   -- Como dice @Candid Moe no responde a la pregunta.